# pandas Series plot color

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I'm writing a generic plotting function that's used in a few different cases. Its input is sometimes a `Series`, sometimes a `DataFrame`. Sometimes I specify the plot color, sometimes I want to use the default behavior.

I would think that passing `color=None` would allow the default color logic to work, but it is not a valid input to `Series.plot`. `DataFrame.plot` allows it, though.

EDIT: Code sample.

```
>>> pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).plot(color=None)
ValueError: Invalid color None
>>> pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]]).plot(color=None)
<AxesSubplot:> # works
```

I'm using pandas v1.4.4.

Comment: Can you provide example code and data that shows what you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't supply `color`, the function will use default value (i.e. `pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]]).plot()`).
It also seems that neither DataFrame nor Series have a keyword `color`. So, if you want to supply `None` use `colormap`.

```
#Both work
pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).plot(colormap=None)
pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]]).plot(colormap=None)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html?highlight=dataframe%20plot#pandas.DataFrame.plot

Comment: According to the documentation, additional arguments (**kwargs) are passed to matplotlib. And `color` works fine as long as I don't pass `None`.

Answer (score 0):

The `pandas` team acknowledged this as a bug and [fixed it](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/51967).